# Can I turn my Mac Mini into a Wi-Fi Hotspot without additional tool

Tags: networking, iphone, wireless-networking, routing, mac-mini

I have an app need to test via wifi.
I just wonder if there is a way to turn my Mac Mini into a Wi-Fi Hotspot without additional tool.
I try to setup airport new network name is"mymacmini'.
My iPod Touch also can recognize the network "mymacmini".
I set my iPod wifi as "mymacmini"
But if I try to connect to Internet, Safari always reports failure and connnection with Wifi.

I hope to know if I need purchase a wireless router for MAc Mini or there are something wrong I did above?

Thanks

interdev

Comment: Yes, just turn on "Internet Sharing" in System Prefs => Sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Apple` => `System Preferences` => `Sharing` => `Internet Sharing`.

Comment: Will this work the same way as a hotspot with account management etc? Or just open access to the network?

Comment: @cdburgess: it just opens up the network - no fancy features